# How to do not null check on LEFT function on the select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns some demographics like firstName, lastName, MiddleName and i need to use LEFT function on each to filter the First Letter of each column like LEFt(firstName, 1).This is working fine when each column is not a null value. when it is null value

```
 select otherColumns, LEFT(sub.LastName, 1) + ',' + LEFT(sub.FirstName, 1) + ' ' + LEFT(sub.MiddleName, 1) as patientInitials from <table> <inner joins> <some where conditions>;
```

But when one of demographics like middleName is null and other firstName, lastName are not null , patientInitials are evaulating to NULL, not sure why?

I resolved my issue by adding **COALESCE**

```
 LEFT(sub.LastName, 1) + ',' + LEFT(sub.FirstName, 1) + ' ' + COALESCE((LEFT(sub.MiddleName, 1)),'') as patientInitials
```

But is there any other good way to check for notNull on the LEFT function ??

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there any other good way to check for notNull on the LEFT function ??

`CONCAT` function ignores NULLs:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(sub.LastName, 1), ',' , 
              LEFT(sub.FirstName, 1),
              ' ' + LEFT(sub.MiddleName, 1)) patientInitials
FROM tab;
```

`' ' + LEFT(sub.MiddleName, 1))` using ' ' will remove leading space in case if Middle Name is `NULL`.

Comment: I'd rather say CONCAT function will _ignore_ NULLs.

Comment: @jarlh Thank you, that's a better wording :)

Comment: @LukaszSzozda what if don't want to CONCAT and want to use just one column LEFT(firstName, 1) and ignore null on it. Do you still recomend to use CONCAT in that case

Answer (score 0):

The `CONCAT_WS` function also has a similar function：[CONCAT_WS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)